Derivation of compound verbs for inversion of action
Can any of these verbs:

返る

返す

戻る

戻す

抜ける

抜く

出る

出す

消える

消す

外れる

外す


... Or any other verb be used productively as component of compound verbs to mean inversion / reversion / reversal / undoing of given action? Or any other productive morphological way?
In dictionaries, I can find cases of usage of some of these verbs (mostly 返す and 戻す) in compound verbs to mean inversion of action, but it is not clear if any are productive.
Prefix 逆{さか} does not seem to be productive, at least for verbs.
English can express inversion of action using prefixes un- (← Middle English on- ← Old English on-, ond-, and-) and dis- (← Middle English dis- ← Latin dis-) (mostly for Latinate words).
Examples in English:

un- +‎ freeze → unfreeze

un- +‎ eat → uneat

un- +‎ drink → undrink

un- +‎ lock → unlock

un- +‎ kill → unkill

dis- +‎ connect → disconnect


E.g. for unfreeze, uneat, undrink, what would be natural derivations based on 凍る, 食べる, 飲む?

凍り返す, 凍り戻す, ...?

食べ返す, 食べ戻す, ...?

飲み返す, 飲み戻す, ...?



返す and 戻す are not productive, and no other affix is as productive as English "un-". 返す may even mean "re-" in some compounds (読み返す = "reread").
If you're looking for short expressions for user interfaces, 解除 works for at least some words, although this is not a suffix but an independent verb:

Unlock: ロック解除 (アンロック is more common among gamers)
Unstar: スター解除
Unfriend: フレンド解除 / 友達解除
Unfollow: フォロー解除

For verbs like "unsee" or "undrink", I think you can use ～しなかったことにする, ～した記憶を消す and such most of the time, but I doubt they can be shorter.
